# Rails routing - optional parameters not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubymine

I have the code below in my routes.rb file:

```
get 'page/contact_us(/:year(/:month))'=>'page#contact_us', :as => 'contact_us'
```

The idea is that entering year and month in the url are optional. But whenever I try to go to the address:

```
localhost:3000/page/contact_us
```

I get an error. It's only when I enter both a year and a month that I don't get an error. For example,

```
localhost:3000/page/contact_us/2014/11
```

works!

Rails tells me that the error is in the contact_us.html.erb file. The error line is:

```
<%=contact_us(@month,@year).html_safe%>
```

The contact_us(month, year) function is defined in a helper file - page_helper.rb

**The idea is that 2 arguments are usually passed above (in the url), but sometimes 1 or no arguments may be passed in the url. I get an error when less than 2 arguments are passed.**

Please help! I'm using rails 4.1.8 and Rubymine

Comment: `contact_us_path(@year)` works for me, as well as `contact_us_path` without arguments.

Comment: If `params[:month]` and `params[:year]` are not defined (and they won't be if you don't pass them in the url).  Then what are you populating `@month` and `@year` with?  What happens in your code if `@month` and `@year` are nil?

Comment: Thanks. params[:month] and params[:year] are for GET requests. For example, something like: localhost:3000/page/contact_us?month=10&year=2012

Comment: Can we see the helper method? And the actual error?

Comment: Actual error is:   <%=calendar(@month,@year).html_safe%>//Invalid date

Comment: Helper method is here: http://www.codeshare.io/V6muo

Comment: I'm thinking you're passing @ month or @year as nil, then trying to create a new date object in your helper method with nil as the month or year, overriding the default values it might have, and creating an invalid Date. Try making optional parameters or adding a line to set month and year to default value if they are nil

Comment: Thanks. how do you add optional parameters?

Comment: I thought that this statement:  get 'page/contact_us(/:year(/:month))'=>"page#contact_us", :as => 'contact_us' -which is in routes.rb makes year and month optional. I thought the parentheses around year and month make it optional. No? @MichaelCruz

Answer (score 0):

Your invalid date error is coming from the calendar method that you included a link to you in your comments. You have:

```
def calendar(month, year)

  current_date = Date.new(year, month, 1)
  ...
```

The problem is that if month or year is nil, you are basically doing this (in this case, assuming both are nil):

```
current_date = Date.new(nil, nil, 1)
```

Just run rails console and try that: you get this error - TypeError: no implicit conversion from nil to integer.

So the problem isn't with your url, its before. You could add some lines like this to fix that error:

```
def calendar(month, year)
  month ||= 1
  year ||= 1900
  current_date = Date.new(year, month, 1)
  ...
```

...but then you'll have to keep track of the fact that those aren't correct dates so that they don't get passed in the url, wherever that happens.